# Customizing embedded Twitter widget tweet hover state

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I've found this particular JS library [customize-twitter](https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1) from other questions on here that I was hoping would help me change the hover background color on my embedded twitter widget.

I might be missing the correct css for that. Or does anyone know if that is possible? I thought it should be:

```
.timeline-Tweet:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 248, 250);
}
```

but this is still not working. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: In the demo, there's a link to a css [file](https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1/blob/gh-pages/twitter.css). Have you tried using that?

Comment: Yep. I saw that but didn't see anything changing the hover bg state. I tried this selector too:

     root.twitter-timeline .u-url:hover

which was in that.

Comment: Well after not working no matter what before, suddenly the css style I had above works now!

Comment: :)) Happens sometimes. Good to hear it worked out for you.

Comment: Ha..And right away it stopped working again. Buggy.